# How to solve the determinant without expanding?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Here is the the determinant equation:
$$
  \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & bc & bc(b+c)\\
   1 & ca & ca(c+a)\\ 
   1 & ab & ab(a+b)\\
  \end{vmatrix} = abc\begin{vmatrix}
                      a & 1 & b+c\\
                      b & 1 & c+a\\
                      c & 1 & a+b\\
                     \end{vmatrix}=0
$$
I am new and beginner in matrices and determinants.So please explain the steps of  the answers.

Comment: I learnt only adding and subtracting or multiplying rows and columns and I can expand.But the problem asked to prove the determinants are zero without expanding.I can't figure out with these skills.

Comment: Can you at least show that the second expression is equal to zero? You should be able to do that with only one operation.

Comment: You should  accept one the answers (even it should be your own answer).  See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. This makes it *visible* that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

It's a famous rule of determinants that

> If we multiply a row (column) of a matrix A by a number, the determinant of A will be multiplied by the same number.

Suppose we are comfortably in $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose also that $a,b,c \ne 0$, then multiply and divide the first row for $a$, the second for $b$ and the third for $c$
$$
  \frac{abc}{abc}\begin{vmatrix}
   1 & bc & bc(b+c)\\
   1 & ca & ca(c+a)\\ 
   1 & ab & ab(a+b)\\
  \end{vmatrix} = \frac{1}{abc}\begin{vmatrix}
                      a & abc & abc(b+c)\\
                      b & abc & abc(c+a)\\
                      c & abc & abc(a+b)\\
                     \end{vmatrix}
$$

Now you can conclude beacuse taking out the $(abc)^2$ factor that multiplies the  second and third column you get

$$
   abc\begin{vmatrix}
                      a & 1& (b+c)\\
                      b & 1 & (c+a)\\
                      c & 1 & (a+b)\\
                     \end{vmatrix}
$$

**EDIT**

At this point, to conclude that the determinant is $0$ you can simply use the Sarrus' rule or, without expanding, you can subtract the first row to the second and third row to get

$$
abc
\begin{vmatrix}
  a & 1 & b+c\\
  b-a & 0 & a-b\\
  c-a & 0 & a-c\\
\end{vmatrix} = abc[(a-b)(c-a) - (a-c)(b-a)] = 0
$$

Notice that in the header of the proof I supposed that $a,b,c \ne 0$, but now we can conclude even if one between $a,b,c = 0$, because the property is satisfied as well.

Comment: In the first equation the factor $abc$ is on the wrong side. What if $abc = 0$?

Comment: Nice.Didn't catch that.But now the second problem.How do I prove that the determinant is zero(0)?

Comment: can someone please explain how to prove that the determinant itself is zero(0)?

Comment: @PaulFrost I seriously can't get what you mean by "the wrong side". However, the supposition that $abc=0$ does not affect the conclusion. I added some details.

Comment: $$
 abc \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & bc & bc(b+c)\\
   1 & ca & ca(c+a)\\ 
   1 & ab & ab(a+b)\\
  \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
                      a & abc & abc(b+c)\\
                      b & abc & abc(c+a)\\
                      c & abc & abc(a+b)\\
                     \end{vmatrix} = (abc)^2\begin{vmatrix}
                      a & 1 & b+c\\
                      b & 1 & c+a\\
                      c & 1 & a+b\\
                     \end{vmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Okay, in your recent edit you shifted the factor $abc$ in your original equation $$
 \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & bc & bc(b+c)\\
   1 & ca & ca(c+a)\\ 
   1 & ab & ab(a+b)\\
  \end{vmatrix} = abc \begin{vmatrix}
                      a & abc & abc(b+c)\\
                      b & abc & abc(c+a)\\
                      c & abc & abc(a+b)\\
                     \end{vmatrix} 
$$
to the correct side.

Comment: Yes, it was a lack of attention. In future consider to edit post instead of answering using almost the same arguments.

Comment: Let us stop bossiness. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a market of upvotes. I still remain in my opinion ahah

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\begin{vmatrix}
                      a & 1 & b+c\\
                      b & 1 & c+a\\
                      c & 1 & a+b\\
                     \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
                      a & 1 & a+b+c\\
                      b & 1 & b+c+a\\
                      c & 1 & c+a+b\\
                     \end{vmatrix} = 0$$
Here the first columm was added to the third. Thus it remains to verify the first equation in your question.

Case 1: $abc = 0$.

In that case at least one of $a, b ,c$ is $0$ and $$
 \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & bc & bc(b+c)\\
   1 & ca & ca(c+a)\\ 
   1 & ab & ab(a+b)\\
  \end{vmatrix}$$
has at least two rows of the form $(1 \quad 0 \quad 0)$ so that the first equation follows.

Case 2: $abc \ne 0$.

Then 
$$
 abc \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & bc & bc(b+c)\\
   1 & ca & ca(c+a)\\ 
   1 & ab & ab(a+b)\\
  \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
                      a & abc & abc(b+c)\\
                      b & abc & abc(c+a)\\
                      c & abc & abc(a+b)\\
                     \end{vmatrix} = (abc)^2\begin{vmatrix}
                      a & 1 & b+c\\
                      b & 1 & c+a\\
                      c & 1 & a+b\\
                     \end{vmatrix} 
$$
In the first step the factor $abc$ was shifted into the determinant by multiplying the first row with $a$, the second with $b$ and the third with $c$. In the second step the factor (abc) was extracted from columns two and three.

Dividing by $abc \ne 0$ yields the desired result.

Comment: You are just saying the same thing I wrote before.. Instead of rewriting the same things, you it was better if you have edited my post, changing the position of that $abc$

Comment: @Gabrielek I guess you are the downvoter ;-)

Comment: @Gabrielek I read your and Paul Frost's answer and the discussion in the comments. Of course I do not know whether you are the downvoter, but nobody should downvote a correct and good answer.

Answer (score 0):

By gaining knowledge from the above answers I think I have figure it out.Please check my answer if I am wrong correct my answer please.

$$
  \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & bc & bc(b+c)\\
   1 & ca & ca(c+a)\\ 
   1 & ab & ab(a+b)\\
  \end{vmatrix} = abc\begin{vmatrix}
                      a & 1 & b+c\\
                      b & 1 & c+a\\
                      c & 1 & a+b\\
                     \end{vmatrix}
$$
On the **left hand side** $Row1*a$, $Row2 * b$, $Row3*c$, On **the right hand side** $Col'3 =Col1 + Col3$
$$
  \begin{vmatrix}
   a & abc & abc(b+c)\\
   b & abc & abc(c+a)\\
   c & abc & abc(a+b)\\
  \end{vmatrix}
=abc\begin{vmatrix}
                      a & 1 & a+b+c\\
                      b & 1 & a+b+c\\
                      c & 1 & a+b+c\\
                     \end{vmatrix}
$$
Now on the **left Hand Side** factoring $abc$ and On the **right hand side** factor $a+b+c$.
$$abc^2\begin{vmatrix}
        a & 1 & b+c\\
        b & 1 & c+a\\
        c & 1 & a+b\\
     \end{vmatrix}=abc(a+b+c)\begin{vmatrix}
                    a & 1 & 1\\
                    b & 1 & 1\\
                    c & 1 & 1\\
                   \end{vmatrix}
$$
Now according to the determinant rule, if a determinant has two identical columns then it's value is 0.Which means **the right side** is 0.
And for the **left hand side** $Col'3 = Col1 + Col3$ and factor a+b+c which eventually lead to the same situation.
$$abc^2\begin{vmatrix}
        a & 1 & a + b + c\\
        b & 1 & a+b+c\\
        c & 1 & a+b+c\\
\end{vmatrix}= abc(a+b+c)*0
$$
$$
  abc^2(a+b+c)\begin{vmatrix}
               a & 1 &1\\
               b & 1 &1\\
               c & 1 & 1\\
              \end{vmatrix}= 0
$$
$abc^2(a+b+c)*0 = 0$

$0=0=0$